# Kubernetes fails to pull images from gitlab registry unknown-sha256: <4ca..252> unexpected commit digest precondition

Tags: docker, kubernetes, gitlab, containerd

Been learning kubernetes in the past several weeks. I've recently built a bare-metal kubernetes cluster with (3) master nodes and (3) worker nodes (containerd runtime). Installed an another stand-alone bare-metal gitlab server with container registry enabled.

I was successful in building a simple nginx container with a custom index.html using docker build and pushed it to the registry; up until this point everything works great.

Now I wanted to create a simple pod using the image built above.
So, did the following steps.

1. Created a deploy token with read_registry access
2. Created a secret in kubernetes with username and the token as the password
3. Inserted `imagePullSecrets` to the deployment yaml file.
4. kubectl apply -f nginx.yaml.

Kubernetes pod status stays in `ImagePullBackOff`.

```
Failed to pull image "<gitlab-host>:5050/<user>/<project>/nginx:v1": rpc error: code = FailedPrecondition desc = failed to pull and unpack image  
"<gitlab-host>:5050/<user>/<project>/nginx:v1": failed commit on ref "unknown-sha256:4ca40a571e91ac4c425500a504490a65852ce49c1f56d7e642c0ec44d13be252": unexpected commit digest sha256:0d899af03c0398a85e36d5cd7ee9a8828e5618db255770a4a96331785ff26d9c, expected sha256:4ca40a571e91ac4c425500a504490a65852ce49c1f56d7e642c0ec44d13be252: failed precondition.
```

Troubleshooting steps followed.

1. `docker login` from another server works.
2. `docker pull` works
3. In one of the worker nodes where kubernetes was scheduling the pod, I did `ctr image pull` which works

Did some googling but couldn't find any solutions.  So, here I am as a last resort to figure this out.
Appreciate any help that I get.

My Deployment nginx.yml file

```
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: nginx
  name: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: <gitlab-host>:5050/<username>/<project>/nginx:v1
        imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
        name: nginx
      imagePullSecrets:
      - name: regcred
```

Comment: how is parameter `imagePullPolicy` is set ?

Comment: I'll add the deployment.yml file to the original post

Comment: try to configure `imagePullPolicy: Always` then deploy again, image should be forced pull in this case

Comment: I tried that. I then changed it to IfNotPresent. But same error

Comment: Tried cleaning `/var/lib/containerd/io.containerd.content.v1.content/ingest/` as some posts suggested but no luck

Comment: try to tag image is `:latest` as well

Comment: Same error with latest as well

Comment: How did you setup bare-metal Kubernetes cluster and Gitlab server? Could you share some instructions that you used? Which Kubernetes version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. I made a silly mistake in `/etc/containerd/config.toml` in the registry section and not mentioning the endpoint with port number `<gitlab-host>:5050`.
And also adding the private registries in config.toml is not necessary unless you want to run ctr command on the k8s nodes.